# Android update listview after changing data using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to implement `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

My app consists of main activity and fragments. The home fragment has a list of URLs with a title, and I would like to add a setting to add a URL to this list. This is what I've tried so far:

Here's the `SettingsFragment.java`:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);
    if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
        String value = editTextPreference.getText();
        new HomeFragment().addLink(value);
    } else {
        assert preference != null;
        preference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

    }
}
```

And the `HomeFragment.java`:

```
private ArrayList<LinkItem> urls = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new LinkItem("LifeHacker RSS Feed", "https://lifehacker.com/rss"),
        new LinkItem("Google News Feed", "https://news.google.com/news/rss");
private LinkItemAdapter itemAdapter;
private ListView listView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.postListView);
    itemAdapter = new LinkItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.link_item, urls);
    listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}

void addLink(String title) {
    urls.add(new LinkItem(title, "https://google.com"));
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HomeFragmentDirections.ActionHomeFragmentToRssFragment action =
                HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToRssFragment(urls.get(position).Link, urls.get(position).Title);
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(HomeFragment.this).navigate(action);
    }
};
```

If I try doing it like this, the itemAdapter will be null, crashing the app, so I am unsure of how to implement this. If I try recreating it in addLink like in the onCreate method of HomeFragment, the activity ends up being null. If I try passing the activity or the context from settings fragment, the same result occurs.

`LinkItemAdapter` adapts the following object:

```
public class LinkItem {
    public String Title;
    public String Link;
}
```

My results so far have always been the same: crash as soon as I click "OK" on the edit text field after changing it, due to a null pointer. Could anyone help me out with this, please? I am new to android.

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myfragmentapp, PID: 5185
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myfragmentapp.adapters.LinkItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myfragmentapp.screens.HomeFragment.addLink(HomeFragment.java:86)
        at com.example.myfragmentapp.screens.SettingsFragment.onSharedPreferenceChanged(SettingsFragment.java:42)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:560)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:443)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java:1632)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.persistString(Preference.java:1663)
        at androidx.preference.EditTextPreference.setText(EditTextPreference.java:80)
        at androidx.preference.EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onDialogClosed(EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:99)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onDismiss(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:267)
        at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1377)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6709)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Comment: Could you add the crash stack trace as well?

Comment: I've linked it in my question

Comment: You stack trace doesn't match what I'm seeing in the code :/

Comment: Oh! sorry, that's because I took the wrong one, sorry about that, I've updated it now

Answer (score 0):

You should call `addLink()` **after** you've created the adapter:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
     listView = view.findViewById(R.id.postListView);
     itemAdapter = new LinkItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.link_item, urls);
     listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
     addLnk();
     return view;
 }
```

If you're trying to set a value from one fragment to another you should either use callbacks or a ViewModel, the simpler of those being a callback:

Define a callback inteface:

```
interface OnSetPreferenceItem{
   void setPrefItemInList(String item);
}
```

Inside SettingsFragment, define a variable:

```
 private OnSetPreferenceItem callback;
```

In the same fragment, fill in the variable in onAttach:

```
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
     super.onAttach(context);

     callback = (OnSetPreferenceItem )context;
 }
```

Now instead of calling  new HomeFragment().addLink(value);, call

```
callback.setPrefItemInList(value);
```

Let your parent activity implement that interface and implement the method suggested:

```
public void setPrefItemInList(String item){
     homeFragment.addLink(item);
}
```

Modify your addLink method to protect it:

```
void addLink(String title) {
   urls.add(new LinkItem(title, "https://google.com"));
    if(itemAdapter!=null){
       itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm calling addlink from within a different fragment (SettingsFragment), so this is not possible. The point is to update it from within the onSharedPreferences method within the SettingsFragment. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: The problem remains the same if I do this, itemAdapter will still be null, results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using the lifecycle functions of the `Fragment` correctly. When you are modifying some data (i.e. adding a new URL in the list) from another fragment (i.e. `SettingsFragment`), you do not have to call the `HomeFragment.addLink` right away actually. Instead, you might consider having the `onResume` method implemented in your `HomeFragment` so that when you go back to your `HomeFragment`, the `onResume` function is called automatically and there you should update your list and consider calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Hence I am trying to provide some pseudo code here. In your `SettingsFragment` do something like the following.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);
    if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
        String value = editTextPreference.getText();

        // new HomeFragment().addLink(value); // You do not call this here
        saveTheNewURLInPrefrence(); // Just save the new value in your preference
    } else {
        assert preference != null;
        preference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

    }
}
```

Now in your `HomeFragment`, implement the `onResume` function like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    urls = getAllItemsFromPreference();

    if(itemAdapter != null) itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    else {

        itemAdapter = new LinkItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.link_item, urls);
        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }

}
```

To understand more about fragment lifecycle, please check the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating). I hope you get the idea.

Comment: How would you suggest implementing `saveTheNewURLInPreference()` and `getAllItemsFromPreference()`?

Comment: [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) you can save a list into `SharedPreference`. Once you can save it, I think you can get it as well.

Comment: If I do this, won't `getActivity()` be null when I call it in `onResume()`?

Comment: Nope. The `onResume` function is called after `onCreateView`. So you are safe. Check the documentation that I provided in the answer again.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this but now the line `SharedPreferences prefs = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_pref2), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in `addItemToPreferences` crashes on a nullpointer, since getActivity is null.